i am running into a problem with chrome's bot detection

Hi everyone. i am trying to make a program in python that will send a loop of messages to a reciepient using my own google voice account. the program works like this:

open google voice via chrome.exe
input username the wait
input password then wait
input recipients number
input text
send
loop from input text
program works until it passes the username input. it should be username input then password input. however after it inputs the username and presses enter, crome's bot detection comes in and says "browser may not be secure", then has a try agian button. i have in the code to try to act more human like definitions. i dont think they are working as intended, (they havent broken the code) but any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
my main goal is to get past the bot detection. i know it wont be easy. im very novice to coding and what i could possibly do. here is my code
    import threading
    import time
    import random
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    # Global variable for the kill switch
    kill_switch = False

    # Function to listen for key press (kill switch)
    def listen_for_kill_switch():
        global kill_switch
        while not kill_switch:
            user_input = input("Press '1' to stop the program: ")
            if user_input == '1':
                kill_switch = True
                print("Kill switch activated! Stopping the program.")

    # Path to ChromeDriver (update this to the correct path on your machine)
    chrome_driver_path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"  # Update this path

    # Set up Chrome options to disable automation detection
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")  # Hide automation
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")  # Remove info bar showing automation control
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Start maximized
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")  # Optionally use incognito mode

    # Optionally, add a custom user-agent to mimic a real browser
    user_agents = [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)             Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
    ]
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}")  # Random user-agent

    # Set up the WebDriver
    service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    # Start the key press listener in a separate thread
    listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_kill_switch)
    listener_thread.start()

    try:
        # Navigate to Google login page
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?   continue=https%3A%2F%2Fvoice.google.com%2Fsignup&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fvoice.google.com%2Fsignup&osid=1&passive=1209600&service=grandcentral&ifkv=AcMMx-foRSvj9aaIkGme-TbLDTEgcVhogjRFWAk2Mtz4tM9eJGMMgIDDRhgXCdo8NvkgQ9b_bhoz&ddm=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin%22)")
    
        # Simulate some human-like delay
        time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))  # Random delay between 2 and 4 seconds

        # Automate the email input with human-like delay
        email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "identifierId"))
        )
        for character in "myemail@gmail.com":  # Replace with your email
            email_input.send_keys(character)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))  # Random delay between keystrokes
    
        email_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Simulate a delay for password input
        time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 5))

        password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
        )
        for character in "your-password":  # Replace with your password
            password_input.send_keys(character)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.3))  # Random delay
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Wait for the login process to complete
        time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 6))

        # Continue with further actions (e.g., sending a message, etc.)
        driver.get("https://voice.google.com")

        # Simulate a pause before interacting with the page
        time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 6))

        # Wait for the "Send a message" button to be clickable and click it
        send_message_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Send a message']"))
        )
        send_message_button.click()

        # Define the recipient's phone number and the list of messages
        phone_number = "1234567890"  # Replace with the recipient's phone number
       messages = [
            "Hello, this is message 1.",
            "This is message 2.",
            "Another test message, number 3.",
            "Final message, number 4!"
        ]

        # Loop through the list of messages and send each one, checking the kill switch
        for message_text in messages:
            if kill_switch:
                print("Kill switch detected! Exiting the loop.")
                break

            # Check for the phone number input field and enter the phone number
            phone_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='tel']"))
            )
            phone_input.clear()  # Clear the input field
            phone_input.send_keys(phone_number)

            # Check for the message input field and enter the message text
            message_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea[aria-label='Message']"))
            )
            message_input.clear()  # Clear the input field
            message_input.send_keys(message_text)

            # Send the message by simulating pressing Enter
            message_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

            print(f"Sent: {message_text}")
   
            # Wait a few seconds before sending the next message to avoid being flagged as spam
            time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 6))  # Adjust the delay as needed

        print("Program completed or stopped by kill switch.")

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions by printing the error message
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    finally:
        # Make sure to close the browser window
        driver.quit()
        print("Browser closed. Program exited.")



You are "very novice to coding", yet you think you can code better than google experts (which is what you are saying if you want your bot to not be detected by google's bot-detection)?

Google's bot-detection is pretty good.  It won't be easy and it's a moving target.  Just use a Google API for this.

Thanks for the constructive critism. i understand that i was going againt a top dog. i just wanted to see if it was possible to do without spending money. i will try the google api instead.

Google voice doesn't have an api? what api should i use?

They really don't want you doing this... so while you can get around the bot-detection, the behavior detection would get your account banned.  I'm sure there are services you can use for this... not sure if any are free, though.

understandable. ill leave this project in the saved failed projects and dust it off another time
